# how to remove blank column from excel while exporting data using php

Tags: javascript, php, export-to-csv

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {
        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td:has(input:checked)),tr:has(th)'),
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11),
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0),
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
        var $row = $(row), $cols = $row.find('td,th');
        return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
        var $col = $(col), text = $col.text();
            return text.replace(/"/g, '""');
        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);
        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
        console.log(csv);
            if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) { 
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([csv], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"}), "csvname.csv")
            } 
            else {
                $(this).attr({ 'download': filename, 'href': csvData, 'target': '_blank' }); 
            }
}
$("#down").on('click', function (event) {
    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dataTable'), 'seimen_data.csv']);
});
```

After selecting data when I click on Download selected data the first column in downloaded `csv` file comes blank. I want to delete that column. Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: any code to share?

Comment: function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

}

Comment: complete code so that i can check the error

Comment: I have added the complete script to download the table data. But on downloading the space for checkbox coming one column blank in CSV file.